# Add new items to a multivalue field instead of override existing values

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I have an *Article* content type with a multi-values taxonomy reference field (field_article_countries) for the *Countries* vocabulary. I also have a *Book* content type with a multi-values taxonomy reference field (*field_book_countries*) for the same vocabulary.

I am trying to:

- Loop through all the loaded articles one by one
- Get all the *field_article_countries* values
- Set those values to *field_book_countries*
- Save the loaded *Book* node

For example, a *Book* node (ID 12) has *field_book_countries* set to *none*. An *Article* node (ID 3) has *field_article_countries* set to *Italy*; another *Article* node (ID 40) has *field_article_countries* set to *Greece, Turkey, Egypt, Brazil, Spain*.

I want to:

- Load the first *Article* node
- Get the value of its *field_article_countries* (*Italy*)
- Load the *Book* node and set its value of *field_book_countries* to *Italy*
- Load the other *Article* node
- Get the values of its *field_article_countries* (*Greece, Turkey, Egypt, Brazil, Spain*)
- Set the *field_book_countries* values for the *Book* node to *Greece, Turkey, Egypt, Brazil, Spain, Italy*
- Save the Book node

The code I am using to achieve this is the following.

```
$articleIDs = [
  '3',
  '40'
];

// Load all the articles.
$articles = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($articleIDs);

// Loop through the loaded articles.
foreach ($articles as $article) {
  // Get the "Countries" Values.
  $countries = $article->get('field_article_countries')->getValue();

  // Set the 'countries' values to the node "book".
  $book->set('field_book_countries', $countries);
  // $book->field_book_countries[] = ['target_id' => $countries];         
}

// Save the Book node.
$book-->save();
```

However, for some reason and during the loop, the new values of *field_book_countries* are overriding the existing one.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! This is a plain PHP question. In the `foreach` loop, you aren't adding items to `$countries`, but you are initializing the variable each time the loop is executed. It can only contain the value assigned the last time the loop is executed. Plus, `$book-->save()` contains an extra `-`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop through all articles, saving all countries in an temp array. When the loop finished save the countries in the book node.

For example:

```
$countries = [];
// Loop through loaded articles.
foreach ($articles as $article) {

    // Get the "Countries" Values.
    $countries = array_merge($countries, $article->get('field_article_countries')->getValue());
}
// Set the 'countries' values to the node "book".
$book->set('field_book_countries', $countries);
// Save Book node.
$book-->save();
```